# How can I merge multiple maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am working on setting up a Survival Games/Hunger Games-type server for a group of friends. I have created a spawn area in an otherwise empty map and would like to import a number of arenas into the map. Some are quite small and I can use MCEdit to export the area from it's own map and then import it into the main map. There are a number of arenas, however, that crash MCEdit when I try to import them as they are so large (i.e Varadie's Survival Games maps). The plugin I am wanting to use needs all arenas to be in the same map. I've also tried using WorldEdit to import schematics but that fails as well, probably due to the large selection area and the server running out of memory.

Are there any other map editors/mergers out there?

Comment: I believe if the areas are aligned to 32x32 chunks you can directly copy and rename the region files `r.<x>.<z>.mca`, but if not you will need a tool like MCEdit, but since the whole map is too large you could try export/import every few chunks individually.

Comment: Given the issue, I feel like your best bet are online map editors that potentially run on stronger PCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use a plugin like multiverse and just simply create a new arena in each world.

Comment: Could you add more information about the plugin and what you do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I found that with Multiverse the arena has to be in the same world as the lobby. So if I have a "spawn" world and a "arena" world it doesn't work, although if you could expand on your answer I would appriciate it.

Comment: @tombull89 Quite late, but if it didn't work, it should **not** be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but it seems you're unable to do this.
All software that merges areas from a map to another does the same.
It will really not matter what program you use, as it is your computer there isn't powerful enough to do it.

I suggest you to export and import smaller areas.
As in, instead of exporting the *whole* arena, try with 1/4. It will take longer, sure, but it will more likely work.